# Conversion from long to short error

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
   short s(0);
   long l(10);

   s += static_cast<short>(l);
}
```

I'm compiling this with g++ and I get the following error:

```
..\src\main.cpp:6:7: warning: conversion to 'short int' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
```

I absolutely have no idea why this is happening, as I thought that "static_cast" permitted to avoid this king of warnings.

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?  [I cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92d6d2ae09aadced)

Comment: @NathanOliver add `-Wconversion` and it triggers the warning.

Comment: Change `s += static_cast<short>(l);` to `s = s + s;` and you still get the warning.  Suggests to me automatic widening of builtin `operator+`  Update: Fount it _"...  arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as arguments,... "_ source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: @Quentin Thanks.  Didn't realize that wasn't included in `-Wall` or `-Wextra`.

Comment: @RichardCritten Oh yeah that's very strange. And so is there any way to fix that instead of overriding operator+ ?

Comment: Try `s = static_cast<short>(s + l);`   Builds clean for me g++ 5.1.0

Comment: @RichardCritten Yep, that works fine, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integral promotion of `short` is required, so widening is unavoidable, however if you perform a `static_cast` you'll cast the result back to a `short`

In a nutshell:

- you're performing a `short` = `short` + `short`

  - (the `static_cast` of the `long` made the second value a `short`)
- Integral promotion happens before the operands are checked for type

  - so you'll get `short` = `int` + `int`
- implicit conversion of the resulting `int` to `short` creates a warning

From [expr]:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield
>   result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result.
>   This pattern is called the usual *arithmetic conversions*, which are defined as follows: 
> ...
> Otherwise, the integral promotions (7.6) shall be performed on both operands. Then the following
>   rules shall be applied to the promoted operands 
>  - If both operands have the same type, no further conversion is needed.

From [conv.prom]

> A prvalue of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, or `wchar_t` whose integer conversion
>   rank (7.15) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type `int` if `int` can represent all the
>   values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type `unsigned int`.

And indeed `short` has a lower rank than `int`:

From [conv.rank]

> The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer type with a
>   smaller size.

For performing the cast (to make the warning go away), see Richard Crittenden's comments on the OP or [Nathan Oliver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46284115/27678)

Answer (score 2):

Even though you are casting `l` to a `short` you still have another conversion that is getting in the way.  When you do

```
 s += static_cast<short>(l);
```

[expr.ass]/7 says it is the same as

```
s = s + static_cast<short>(l)
```

And this transformation is what is giving you the `int` in the warning you receive.

The reason for this is the built in operators don't exist for types smaller than `int`.  Since both types are `short` they are converted to `int` which gives you an `int` for the result and now you are trying to assign that `int` to a `short` which could overflow.  To workaround this you can use

```
s = static_cast<short>(s + l);
```

which converts the result to a `short` and then does the assignment.